# What is the partition function of a classical harmonic oscillator?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, partition-function

A **classical** harmonic oscillator has energy given by $\frac{1}{2m}p^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2$. This means its Boltzmann factor is

$$e^{-\frac{\beta p^2}{2m}}e^{-\frac{\beta k x^2}{2}}$$

where $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{p}$ are the continuous position and momentum vectors, respectively. The partition function should therefore be given by

$$Z=\int e^{-\frac{\beta p^2}{2m}}d^3\vec{p}\int e^{-\frac{\beta k x^2}{2}}d^3\vec{x},$$

but it is stated in my course homework that the partition function is instead

$$Z=\frac{1}{h^3}\int e^{-\frac{\beta p^2}{2m}}d^3\vec{p}\int e^{-\frac{\beta k x^2}{2}}d^3\vec{x}.$$

Some sources online have instead a factor $\frac{1}{h}$ but without any justification. Either way, I cannot see how $h$ enters into this calculation. Where does it come from?

Comment: Isn't it just some dimensional analysis ? p*x having the dimension of h. So that'd go in the denominator of your d^3 p.

Comment: Sure, but there may be a factor there as well.

Comment: To get a cpartition function for the a 3d classical harmonic oscillator that's "correct" --- meaning, that gets closer and closer to the partition function for the quantum harmonic oscillator in the limit $h \to 0$ --- we need a factor of $1/h^3$, as we see in your second formula.     In any event, your first formula is wrong because the partition function must be dimensionless, and your first formula gives a quantity with dimensions of action cubed.

Answer (score 5):

Classical partition function is defined up to an arbitrary multiplicative constant. dividing it by $h$ is done traditionally for the following reasons:

- In order to have a dimensionless partition function, which produces no ambiguities, e.g., when taking its logarithm
- It provides a smooth junction with the quantum case, since otherwise some of the quantities would differ due to the arbitrary choice of the constant in the classical case, which is however not arbitrary in the quantum treatment.

And many textbooks do explain this.