# Partition function for a classical two-particle oscillator: Infinite limits?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, partition-function

Previous page: [What is the partition function of a classical harmonic oscillator?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589871/)
Whenever I see the partition function of a *classical* two-particle oscillator,

$$Z(\beta) \, = \, \int dx \int dp ~ e^{-\beta H(x,p)} \, = \, \int dx ~ e^{-\beta k x^2} \int dp ~ e^{-\beta \frac{p^2}{2m}},$$

the $x$ and $p$ integration limits go from $(-\infty,\infty)$.  I assume that these limits come from the approximation that the energy of the system can continuously range from $[0,\infty)$.

But I'm wondering if that's the whole story.  Since

$E \, = \, \frac{p^2}{2m} + kx^2 \, = \, \mathrm{constant}$,

we find that $x$ and $p$ actually depend on each other.  We can see this more easily when I rewrite the equation as

$x \, \rightarrow \, x(p) \, = \, \pm \, \sqrt{\frac{1}{k}\left[E - \frac{p^2}{2m}\right]}$ or ${p \, \rightarrow \, p(x) \, = \, \pm \, \sqrt{2m\left[E - k x^{2}\right]}}$.

Note that when $p = 0$ we get the maximum $x$ limits $x_{max} \, = \, \pm \, \sqrt{E/k}$.

Instead of independent infinite integration limits, shouldn't we use these instead:

$Z(\beta) \, = \, \int_{-x_{max}}^{+x_{max}} dx \int_{-p(x)}^{+p(x)} dp ~ e^{-\beta k x^2} ~ e^{-\beta \frac{p^2}{2m}}$?

I used these limits when calculating the average energy.  The result is more complicated, of course, compared to the average energy calculated using the infinite limits.  As $x_{max} \rightarrow \infty$, the average energy using the dependent limits approaches the average energy using the infinite integrals.

Is there a reason why we don't use dependent limits?

Comment: You're missing a factor of 1/2 in the potential energy term $k x^2$. Also, where are the two particles here? This looks like the partition function for a single harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Yes, I didn't include the factor of 1/2, which I believe is standard.  It doesn't change the results of this question.  It is a simple harmonic oscillator, which can be viewed in a number of ways, including two particles on a spring or two atoms in a molecule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dependence of *p* on *x* (or the other way around) only comes from the condition of *constant energy*. This is a natural condition for a microcanonical ensemble, but it is wrong in the canonical ensemble. Remember that the canonical ensemble corresponds to the physical situation of a system (the harmonic oscillator) in contact with a thermostat at a fixed temperature $T$. Under such a condition, the oscillator's energy fluctuates, and every possible value of the energy is allowed (although with different probability). As a consequence, there is no relation between position and momentum, and integrations are over the unrestricted phase space.

Comment: Excellent.  Very clear and concise.  Thanks.  BTW, I wouldn't have thought about using dependent limits for a many-particle system because all of the interactions would make setting it up impossible.  I guess the difference between a microcanonical and canonical ensemble still holds even for two particles.

Comment: @NickElias I agree that the difference between a microcanonical and canonical ensemble still holds even for two particles.